# How to display data in a RecylerView with multiple collections from Firestore in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

What is the best way to display data in a RecylerView in Android from FireStore?

My Firestore database has two collections as following.

```
Posts
 ---  Title
 ---  Image
 ---  User_ID

Users
 ---  User_ID
 ---  User_Name
```

I want to display Posts in a RecylerView with Title(Posts),Image(Posts) and User_Name(Users).

So what is the best way to fetch data from Firestore? What is the recommend way to write an adapter for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use retrofit to fetch the data and put it into pojo class objects.
And pass it into recyclerView's adapter.

Comment: I can fetch the post data and display in a RecylerVIew. But my problem is we can not join collection in Firestore.  I want to display user_name in a post. To do this again I want fetch user details from User collection. What I want to know is that the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As said in a youtube video from Google, you need to add some user details in Posts collection like his name and icon url. Link to the specified video : https://youtu.be/v_hR4K4auoQ?t=6m40s

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [`FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore)

> `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` — binds a `Query` to a `RecyclerView` and responds to all real-time events included items being added, removed, moved, or changed. Best used with small result sets since all results are loaded at once.